# Can I acquire USA visa if new created company will send invitation

Tags: usa, visa

I am CTO of company, which just need to be created, though we have product already 8 months without company.
I am living in Armenia and I am 17 years old and want to go to USA for accelerators and other staff, my partner is vice president of North American headquarter of one worldwide very known company.
He is CEO of our company and can personally give me invitation, though I am thinking that we should officially create company and then as I am co founder he send me invitation.

which is better personal invitation or company invitation?, please note that company is just just should be created and I will be co founder.

I want to ask is it possible to be co-founder for non US resident which 17 years old? (sorry if not related to this stack exchange site).

And what is chances that I can get visa of USA for E-2 or O-1 or other types?,

Also note that I can invest small amount (20K).

**Please note that I have no things that can approve that I will return, though I am creating company and work places in USA. I am not going as worker, but I want to create business in USA.**

Comment: Seems to me from your description that a [B-1](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf) visa would be more appropriate to your circumstances. I managed to get one while in my mid 20's (about 15 years ago) while running my own business in my home country, but things have changed a bit since then ...